# Smooth solutions to integral equation.

Tags: integration, integral-equations, holder-spaces

I was wondering if anyone might be able to give me an answer to the following, or at least point me to a reference that will allow me to figure it out.

I have an integral equation of the following form:

$g(x,y)=\int K(x,z)f(z,y)dz$

Where $g$  and $K$  are known.

First of all, for this to have a solution do I generally need $y$  to be a scalar (i.e. could there still be a solution when $y$ is a vector of some predetermined length). Secondly, are there simple conditions I can place on $g$ and $K$ that guarantee a solution $f$ to the above exists (no need for uniqueness) that is smooth (e.g. satisfies a Holder condition or something like that).

Any help appreciated, have been searching around the web for answers for days and haven't found what I'm looking for.

Comment: Colton and Kress have a number of books on linear integral equations that give theorems for existence and uniqueness. That may be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.